How To Install OpenBoard on Ubuntu 24.04 version
How can I get openboard on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ?

You've not told us what architecture you're using, but I see it available openboard | 1.6.4+dfsg-1build8 | noble/universe    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x so did you try?
